# PHPUnit mock a method call to make it return the arguments

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have mocked my class and can run the tests

But I hace one line in my code that should return the same value as I give it.

```
$products = $this->applyFilterOptions($products);
```

I tried things like:

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('applyFilterOptions')->andReturn(function(&$matches):array {
   $matches = func_get_args();
   return True;
```

});

But I get: *`Return value must be of type array, Closure returned`*

Comment: Welcome to [es.so] .  Tu pregunta deberia  estar escrita en castellano o trasladar la pregunta a [so]